# Ruby Readline crashes console on up arrow

Tags: ruby, rvm, readline, rails-console

When I press the up or left arrow in the Rails console I get this bug:

```
irb(main):001:0> /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4269:in `block in _rl_dispatch_subseq': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

I use `rvm` to manage my ruby installations.  I'm using

```
=> ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

I use `bundle` to manage my gems, and I have `rb-readline (0.4.2)` (which people recommend as the *least* buggy version).

What do I need to do to eliminate this hideous bug once and for all?

I'm on `Mac OS X 10.8.3`.  My `rvm requirements` are already up to date:

```
$ rvm requirements
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
```

Comment: do you have `LANG` set?

Comment: sorry i dont know what that is

Comment: run in your shell `echo $LANG`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

uninstall the `rb-readline` gem - RVM should get `readline` headers for compiling `ruby` which in turn should make ruby `readline` compiled and all should work

Comment: You may try to update gem version: `bundle update rb-readline`. For me version upgrade from 0.5.4 to 0.5.5 worked.